# Is it possible to read contents of a file uploaded with CarrierWave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I followed this example, [File uploads with CarrierWave](https://richonrails.com/articles/allowing-file-uploads-with-carrierwave) to upload an excel file (Classlist) in my application. The file contains the student names, surnames and gender.

When uploading, User will give a name and subject for this "**Class**". Which will then be stored in ***MyClasses*** table. I want to know if I can read the contents of the file and save contents (names,surnames,gender) in the Student table?

The excel file uploaded looks like this...

[image: Classlist]

Comment: I had a similar task and I used the [roo](https://github.com/roo-rb/roo) gem for that problem.

Comment: Carrierwave is for uploading the file not for reading the content of file .If you want to achieve this functionality refer these links  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309511/how-do-i-read-the-content-of-an-excel-spreadsheet-using-ruby  and this http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and suggestions. I'll look into these.